# How to check if strings are same but one has repeated chars

Tags: python, sorting

If I have some strings (Example strings: `["niiiice", "niiiiiiiceee", "nice", "yummy", "shiiinee", "shine", "hello", "print", "priintering", "priinter", "Howdy", "yuup", "yup", "soooouuuuuppppp", "soup", "yeehaw"]`) how do I **check** if they are similar and just have repeated chars and then **find** which of the two in the check should go first (smallest first)? (Example output: `["nice", "niiiice", "niiiiiiiceee", "yummy", "shine", "shiiinee", "hello", "print", "priinter", "priintering", "Howdy", "yup", "yuup", "soup", "soooouuuuuppppp", "yeehaw"]`

NOTE:

If possible the check should leave everything else in the same order. By this I mean if there are more strings that don't have similar counterparts would they stay in roughly the same location.

Comment: You need to be very precise about what you expect. Can there only be one repeated char? The string matching is the difficult part and it needs those king of details. The sorting by size is trivial once the strings are grouped.

Comment: Please provide more test examples of inputs and corresponding outputs. Like 5-10 more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could squeeze out repeated chars, so that "similar" strings become *equal*.

```
import re

a = ["niiiice", "niiiiiiiceee", "nice", "shiiinee", "shine"]

def squeeze(s):
    return re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1', s)

a.sort(key=lambda s: (squeeze(s), len(s)))

print(a)
```

Output:

```
['nice', 'niiiice', 'niiiiiiiceee', 'shine', 'shiiinee']
```

Alternatively, if you only want to sort consecutive groups of "similar" strings:

```
from itertools import groupby
import re

a = ["niiiice", "niiiiiiiceee", "nice", "yummy", "shiiinee", "shine", "hello", "print", "priintering", "priinter", "Howdy", "yuup", "yup", "soooouuuuuppppp", "soup", "yeehaw"]

def squeeze(s):
    return re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1', s)

a = [s for _, g in groupby(a, squeeze) for s in sorted(g, key=len)]

print(a)
```

Output:

```
['nice', 'niiiice', 'niiiiiiiceee', 'yummy', 'shine', 'shiiinee', 'hello', 'print', 'priintering', 'priinter', 'Howdy', 'yup', 'yuup', 'soup', 'soooouuuuuppppp', 'yeehaw']
```

Comment: Will this everything else in the same order?

Comment: @TRCK What do you mean?

Comment: I updated the question to show this but if there are more strings that don't have similar counterparts would they stay in roughly the same location?

Comment: They're sorted by their squeezed version, so whether they say roughly in the same location depends on that and on where they were originally.

Comment: I just tested this and it is very close but I don't want it sorted alphabetically, just the similar words. The output it gave: `['Howdy', 'hello', 'nice', 'niiiice', 'niiiiiiiceee', 'print', 'priinter', 'priintering', 'shine', 'shiiinee', 'soup', 'soooouuuuuppppp', 'yeehaw', 'yummy', 'yup', 'yuup']`

Comment: @TRCK Have a look at the second solution I just added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244753/discussion-between-trck-and-kelly-bundy).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
sorted(["niiiice", "niiiiiiiceee", "nice", "shiiinee", "shine"], key=lambda s: ([k for k, v in itertools.groupby(s)], len(s)))
```

Comment: Will this everything else in the same order

Comment: I just tested this and it is very close but I don't want it sorted alphabetically, just the similar words